# TypeError when using Jquery and Object property function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error when using jquery and I would like to know its cause:

here is part of my code

```
function Wbook(name){
this.name = name;
}

Wbook.prototype.GetHTML = function() {

Object.defineProperty(this, "GetHTML", {enumerable : false,
                           configurable : true});

var html ='<h1>TEST1</h1>';
return html;
};

var rs = {};

rs.WB = new Wbook('test1');

var foo = rs.WB.GetHTML(); 
$(foo).appendTo('div#id1'); // This works

$(rs.WB.GetHTML()).appendTo('div#id1'); 
// This doesn't work >> TypeError: rs.WB.GetHTML is not a function
```

I can also getting to work if I comment the `Object.defineProperty` section, so I'm suspecting this might have to do with the enumerability, but I'm not sure of it

//Edit: While creating [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaLBK/), I notice `rs.WB.GetHTML()` is always failing the second time it runs :-/. (It works fine if I comment the `Object.defineProperty` section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `.GetHTML()` it's returning some HTML, but in the process the `Object.defineProperty` call is *overwriting* the `.GetHTML` method with a new property that has *no value*.

It's therefore unsurprising that on the second invocation you get an error because the value of `.GetHTML` by then is `undefined`.

If the intent of your code is to ensure that `GetHTML` is not enumerable, use the following code which directly adds the method to `Wbook.prototype` and (automatically) sets it non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Wbook.prototype, 'GetHTML', {
    value: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: and this override is happening in the `Object.defineProperty(this, "GetHTML", {enumerable : false,configurable : true});` section right? If so, is there a way to just add the `enumerable : false`, without overriding the method?

Comment: yes - see edit.  When you used `this` it attempted to create a new property on the _instance_, not modify the _existing_ property on the `prototype`.

Comment: thanks, I got it to work now, just one little thing, there is a typo in the answer: protoype. Thanks again